# Creating bootstrap grid with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an array of products. I would like to display them in rows, with 4 products per row. Right now my code is

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products" class="col-md-3">
    <p> {{product.name}} </p>
    <p> {{product.price}} </p>
</div>
```

However, this is not displaying properly. I have tried to incorporate rows with an ng-if, but this is as close as I've come:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products">
    <div ng-if="$index %4 == 0" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            (content)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="$index %4 != 0" class="col-md-3">
        (content)
    </div>
</div>
```

I think I know why the above doesn't work: if `index %4 != 0`then the column that is created is not actually put inside of the row made before.

Is there an angular way to do this? Do I need a custom directive? Note: I have managed a solution not using angular directives but it doesn't seem clean, so I would like to do it "angularly" if possible.

Comment: You reference rows, but then use bootstrap columns, perhaps you can show what you'd like the html to look like?

Comment: I would like it to be a series of rows, each of which contains 4 columns. The reason I used columns in my solution was that I assumed doing col-3's would just start new rows every 4 columns, however it didn't work out cleanly. So I'm thinking I need to use rows to wrap the columns

Comment: It does workout cleanly for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ubexop9p/ (adjust to fit correct size) what exactly is not working out for you?

Comment: see my answer below - it was a problem with the content i was putting inside the divs. sorry for wasting everyone's time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use your first method just fine, here's the html I wired up in a js fiddle:

```
<div ng-app="app">
     <div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
         <div class="container">
             <div class="row">
                 <div data-ng-repeat="option in options" class="col-md-3">
                     {{ option }}
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ubexop9p/

You will have to play around with the frame sizes if your monitor is too small, but I was able to get it do what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have that wrapped in a `container` or `container-fluid`?  I believe that's required for the grid system to work.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="col-md-3">Col 1</div>
   <div class="col-md-3">Col 2</div>
   <div class="col-md-3">Col 3</div>
   <div class="col-md-3">Col 4</div>
   <div class="col-md-3">Col 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I have them in a container, but not directly. There is a container, in the container is a row with a col-2 (sidebar) and a col-10 . All of this logic is in the col-10.

Comment: What is it actually rendering?  I think if you have this within a `div class="col-md-10"`, with each one being 3 wide you will only get 3 per row?  Seems like the 4th would wrap to a new row since it would need 12 columns, and it's container only has 10.

Comment: I tried removing all the content and just putting text in the columns and it works, so I think it was a problem with the content (in particular, I was putting images)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a problem with the content I was putting inside the columns, the code I posted does in fact work.